# Java: My valid date checker program does not work for leap years

Tags: java, date, input

Currently, I am writing a program that asks the user to input a day,month,year. The program then checks whether the date is valid or not. However, for February, I can't get it to output the correct response when the input is a leap year.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ValidDate{

public static void main(String[]args){

    int day,month,year;

    day = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a day"));
    month = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a month"));
    year = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a year"));

    switch(month){  //this statement will check whether or not the days are valid
        case 1:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 31 ){
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 28 || month % 4 == 0 && day >= 1 && day <= 29 ){   //look at 
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }
        case 3:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 31 ){
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }
        case 4:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 30 ){
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }
        case 5:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 31 ){
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }
        case 6:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 30 ){
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }
        case 7:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 31 ){
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }
        case 8:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 31 ){
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }
        case 9:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 30 ){
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }
        case 10:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 31 ){
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }
        case 11:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 30 ){
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }
        case 12:
            if ( day >= 1 && day <= 31 ){
                System.out.println("Date is valid");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Date is not valid");
            }//case ended
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get when I input a leap year is

```
Date is not valid
Date is valid
Date is valid
Date is valid
Date is valid
Date is valid
Date is valid
```

Comment: You forgot about `break;` in most of your cases.

Comment: For leap years, you are validating month % 4 == 0 ?? , validation should be on year ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
month % 4 == 0
```

to:

```
year % 4 == 0
```

If you are trying this for study purpose fine. Otherwise, you can validate leap year using:

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
if (gc.isLeapYear(year))
```

[GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

Comment: Just changed the month to year, thanks for the information on the calendar class though, I will try using that from now

Answer (score 0):

Without the

> break;

statement, once it has found the right case, it will fall through and execute the next ones as well. Unless you are creating bulk cases, add the break statement
What I mean with bulk-cases:

```
enum Day {
  MONDAY,
  TUESDAY,
  WEDNESDAY,
  THURSDAY,
  FRIDAY,
  SATURDAY,
  SUNDAY;

  public boolean isWorkDay() {
    switch(this) {
      case SATURDAY:
      case SUNDAY:
        return false;
      default:
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My bad - still applies to students doing babysitting and stuff.